# Using Google Font in PHP GD

Tags: php, fonts, google-font-api, php-gd

I am trying to use a custom font in an image made with PHP GD.

I intend to call `int imageloadfont(string $file)`, but I'm not sure what `$file` to give if I want to get a Google Font directly from their website.

Do I need to download the font or is there a way to get it remotely?

Comment: You most likely want to download the font to a temporary location anyway, for both performance and safety reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .ttf file from Google servers directly if you have allow_url_fopen enabled in your PHP installation. Look into the stylesheet to get the correct url.

However, for best performance, availability and security, you should download the file and use a local path.

Comment: Ouch! Each time I see `allow_url_fopen`, I die a little bit inside. All right, I'll download that file and put it on my server. Thanks for your answer!